# WPF WebBrowser free up the viewing process

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control

Have a problem when i want to pass another file (pdf) to view in WebBrowser, before if exists try to delete it, but it is impossible. The error is: "System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C: \ Users ...".

I tried to use Dispose() and create a new web browser (i can't see again the file), set Source = null, Navigate("about:blank") but nothing.

I need to delete the file beacause i can put another file in WebBrowser.

Thanks!

```
    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
         File.Delete(file);
    }
           
    file= System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "file.pdf";
}

           
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file)) this.webBrowser.Navigate("file:\\" + file);
```

Comment: The file is blocked by another process. You have to close the other process or the file in it.